# How to solve function equations?

Tags: functions

Consider:
$$g(x)=x^{1/3}$$ 
$$f(g(x))=2x+3$$

Find $f(x)$

It should be fairly obvious that a solution is $f(x)=2x^3+3$

But is this solution unique? And what method should I use to solve such an equation if I don't "see" the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have an equation $f(g(x)) =h(x) $ where $g$ and $h$ are known, and $g$ has an inverse. Defining $y=g(x)$, we have $f(y) =h(g^{-1} (y))$, which is the solution. If $g$ does not have a unique inverse (that is, the inverse of $g(x) $ depends on x), then the solution for $f$ will not be unique.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to invert $g$:

$$y=x^{1/3}\iff x=y^3$$

and there is no "other" inverse.

Then

$$f(x)=f(g(g^{-1}(x)))=f(g(x^3))=2x^3+3.$$

Comment: Why this downvote ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the solution is unique.
You have two functions, $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

For every $x$, $g(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$. You have the cube root function, and it is a bijection.

For every $x$, $f(g(x))=2x+3$. Then $f(\sqrt[3]{x})=2x+3$ for every $x$.
Since cube root is a bijection, you can conclude that $f(x)=2x^3+3$.